# python - how to get key code of control keys

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to get the key code for keys such as: Shift, VolumeUp, play/pause, F12 or PrtScreen.

The code

```
import msvcrt
return msvcrt.getch()
```

only returns codes for letters and numbers and doesn't return it for the whole keyboard.

Thank you for any help in advance!

**I am using windows

Comment: A browser search for "Python key code F12" got immediate useful hits.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, did you try with `Tkinter`? There a lot of tutorials on web, this for [example](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) , here it goes an example from there that maybe you could use:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    print "pressed", repr(event.char)

def callback(event):
    frame.focus_set()
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't return the code of the key.. It returns "pressed + the name of the key I pressed"... Plus, it doesn't work on control keys like Shift, VolumeUp, play/pause, F12 or PrtScreen (returns an empty string). Is there a diffrent way to do it?